# Is there a way to use a custom header for only one column in react ag-grid?

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid

I'm trying to add select all checkbox in header. I know that in most cases I can just add headercheckboxselection in columndefs but in my case it doesn't work since there's no event for that checkbox specifically.

I want the selectall checkbox to have eventlistener and I don't want to change other column headers.

Thank you!